# access to user settings of Chromium/Firefox SNAP packages

Tags: firefox, chrome, xubuntu, snap

Do I have any chance to manage the settings of Chromium or Firefox when they are run via SNAP?

I have a multiuser environment where I'd like to

- install ublock extension by default
- force it to use a proxy
- set the homepage to some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so with snap it's done by creating a json file (eg. policy.json) in /var/snap/chromium/current/policies/managed/ which is picked up directly if you change it while chromium is running. go to chrome://policy and check results. ther are also docu-links to all settings.
For enforcing uBlock Origin just put this in the file:

```
{
  "ExtensionInstallForcelist": [
    "cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
  ]
}
```

make sure to check for syntax errors eg. via

```
jq < /var/snap/chromium/current/policies/managed/policy.json
```